# Send unauthenticated mail using SmtpClient with TLS 1.2 to Microsoft 365

Tags: .net, webforms, office365, smtpclient, .net-4.8

My understanding is that, starting January 2021, Microsoft will require TLS 1.2 to send mail using 365 connectors.
I have a connector working perfectly, that allows relaying the messages coming from the public IPs of my network. I use it since years for a big web application, for document scanner machines and other local applications. I use a 365 service shared mailbox (services@mydomain.com) as sender, without using authentication.

I never succeded to set it to work with TLS, so most of the traffic flows unencrypted. I found a lot of similar questions, but none with the same configuration and absolutely none with an acceptable answer (most answers simply say "don't use SSL").

I want to start fixing TLS on my web application, then fix the rest. This is a .Net 4.8 web form project in c#.

The web.config file includes this settings:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="mydomain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com" port="25" enableSsl="true" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

In the web page, I send messages this way:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
            using SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress("services@mydomain.com", "Tester"),
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                Subject = "Test message",
                Body = "Test message."
            };
    
            msg.To.Add("xxx@mydomain.com");
            client.Send(msg);
```

Now the funny part. This works perfeclty on my client computer, a Windows 11 machine. The message is correctly delivered and, inspected, uses TLS 1.2 in all the bounces.

When I move the same code on the Windows 2016 production server, with the same web.config settings, this does not work. I get the error: **Server does not support secure connections** (logged in the Event Viewer as Event 1309, SmtpException, stack trace:

```
 in System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
 in System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
 in System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Changing the port to 587 does not work. The only way to have the server send messages is to set the web.config section to `enableSsl="true"`. This is of course unacceptable, as it will stop working once Microsoft will stop relaying the unsecured mail.

The firewall allows the traffic. This must be something in the Windows Server setup, but TLS 1.2 is used elsewhere in the same server, so I don't understand what may be the cause.

Comment: This seems to be for ServerFault . I dont think it has to be with config nor code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use .NET `SmtpClient` for SSL

I used this library https://github.com/nilnull/AIM for that. I had to rebuild it in .NET core but there was no need for code changes.

You can then:

```
var smtpClient = new MimeMailer(host) {
  Port = 465,
  User = ,
  Password = ,
  SslType = SslMode.Ssl,
  AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationType.Base64
};
```

and send.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up using Graph.